# NestJS dynamic id and internal array in a dto

Tags: nestjs

How do I create a structure with dto that brings me this as a result:

```
123456: [
           {
              name: "lorem",
              surname. "lorem"
           }]
```

the goal is to create a dto or class where the id is dynamic from time to time I generate it through the user id and internally there is an array of different things

Comment: Will it always be a number, or should it be a string? Are you needing to validate this as a DTO or just represent it in Typescript

Comment: dto for db is string 12345 is an example how to declare ?

Comment: A simple type declaration would be something like `Record<string, InternalObjectType[]>`. Making that for a DTO that can have metadata attached for validation is much more difficult

Comment: Can you write a pastebin with example ?